# VSCode OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

After upgrading my spring boot project to 3.1.5, I am having this issue during test runs in debug console :-

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
```

any help?

Trying to add _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx6G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the following solution which works for me :-

```js
// Add the following to your settings.json
"java.test.config": {
        "vmArgs": [
            "-Xshare:off"
        ]
    },
```